# Python 3.8: IndexError when using append()

Tags: python, list, console, append, index-error

I made a little "console" that splits the command with `split()`. I am separating the "command" (the first "word" from the `input()`) from the "arguments" coming after the first word. Here's the code that generates an error:

```
cmdCompl = input(prompt).strip().split()
cmdRaw = cmdCompl[0]
args = addArgsToList(cmdCompl)
```

`addArgsToList()` function:

```
def addArgsToList(lst=[]):
    newList = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        newList.append(lst[i+1])
    return newList
```

I try to add every word after `cmdRaw` to a list called `args` which is returned by `addArgsToList()`. But what I get instead is:

```
Welcome to the test console!

Type help or ? for a list of commands

testconsole >>> help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testconsole.py", line 25, in <module>
    args = addArgsToList(cmdCompl)
  File "testconsole.py", line 15, in addArgsToList
    newList.append(lst[i+1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I cannot figure out why I get an `IndexError` because as far as I know, `newList` can be dynamically allocated.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do like this:

if you wish to avoid first element to be appended

```
def addArgsToList(lst=[]):
    newList = []
    for i in range(1,len(lst)):
        newList.append(lst[i])
    return newList
```

if you just trying to copy the elements in a new list just do this:

```
newList = lst[1:].copy()
```

Comment: To have the same result but shorter, could I also just do `newList = lst.copy()` and then `del newList[0]`?

Comment: @Dudek_07 I have edited the answer to suit your question

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    newList.append(lst[i+1])
```

The last iteration tries to access `lst` at `len(lst)` which is out of bound.